# Can a PCIe endpoint have several outbound request with same TAG?

Tags: endpoint, dma, pci, pci-e

I aware that if an PCIe endpoint send several read request to the host, the completion packets returned may not be in order, and then we need the `tag` field to reorder them.

But I want to know if there is another way to identify the CPLD TLP?

For example, if I send 2 read request of 128 Bytes with the same `tag` to the host, by return, if the CPLDs don't arrive in order, then is there any chance that I can identify and reorder them?

---

> **Abbreviations:**
>   TLP - Transaction Layer Protocol
>   CPLD - Completion Data

Comment: This might be better suited for [electronics.se], not sure many programmers will have knowledge of how things work this close to the wire.  Check the tags there for PCIe and see if they have some folks with the knowledge you need.

Comment: @Will The transaction layer protocol if far away from the wires :)

Comment: @Paebbels hey, as Einstein pointed out, everything is relative...

Answer (score 0):

CPLDs can not get out of order, as long as they are send with the same traffic class (TC), which feeds all packets through the same virtual channel (VC). Reordering is done between different VCs with different priority. So 2 read requests will be answered in the same order. A responder might combine both reads to one completion if you are addressing consecutive addresses!

Answer (score 0):

As per **PCI EXPRESS BASE SPECIFICATION** , [PCIe CPLD Ordering for same Transaction ID must be in order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TQpn.png) Refer Transaction Ordering Table 2-34, rule D5b, CPLD must be in order.